# Is it thread-safe when using tf.Session in inference service?

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

Now we have used TensorFlow to train and export an model. We can implement the inference service with this model just like how `tensorflow/serving` does.

I have a question about whether the `tf.Session` object is thread-safe or not. If it's true, we may initialize the object after starting and use the singleton object to process the concurrent requests.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `tf.Session` object is thread-safe for [`Session.run()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/client.html#Session.run) calls from multiple threads.

Before TensorFlow 0.10 graph modification was not thread-safe. This was fixed in the 0.10 release, so you can add nodes to the graph concurrently with `Session.run()` calls, although this is not advised for performance reasons; instead, it is recommended to call [`sess.graph.finalize()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/framework.html#Graph.finalize) before using the session from multiple threads, to  prevent accidental memory leaks.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot. Is it necessary to add this in document? Any one uses TensorFlow may implement the inference service for their models and it is important to do it on the right way.

Comment: Can a minimal example using Keras be provided.